# pandas reset_index() function

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone explain the function and working of the reset_index() function in pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

def count_unique_subjects(teacher: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Group by teacher_id and count the number of unique subject_ids
    result = teacher.groupby('teacher_id')['subject_id'].nunique().reset_index()
    result.rename(columns={'subject_id': 'cnt'}, inplace=True)

    return result
```

I tried running some programs and i am not sure how it works. If I remove the reset_index() it doesn't work.

Comment: It just moves the index to column, hoverer here you could also use `as_index=False` in your groupby.

Comment: The `reset_index()` function in Pandas is used to reset the index of a DataFrame. In pandas, when you perform operations like grouping, filtering, or aggregating data, the resulting DataFrame often has a modified index. The `reset_index()` function is used to revert these changes and bring the DataFrame back to its original index or create a new default integer-based index.